# Using traits with data classes in Kotlin?

Tags: traits, kotlin

I have two model objects / DTOs defined as data classes

```
public data class ModelA(val limit: Int, val offset: Int, val someDataA: DataAlpha)
public data class ModelB(val limit: Int, val offset: Int, val someDataB: DataBeta)
```

I would like to generalize pagination based on something like **Paginable** trait:

```
trait Paginable {
    var limit: Int
    var offset: Int
}
```

But making ModelA implement Paginable causes an error:

*Error: 'offset' hides member of supertype 'Paginable' and needs 'override' modifier*

Adding *override*:

```
public data class ModelB(override val limit: Int, override val offset: Int, val someDataB: DataBeta) : Paginable
```

causes even more interesting error, crashing the compiler:

```
Error:java.lang.ClassCastException: org.jetbrains.kotlin.psi.JetParameter cannot be cast to org.jetbrains.kotlin.psi.JetProperty
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.resolve.OverrideResolver$3.varOverriddenByVal(OverrideResolver.java:562)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.resolve.OverrideResolver.checkOverridesForMemberMarkedOverride(OverrideResolver.java:606)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.resolve.OverrideResolver.checkOverrideForMember(OverrideResolver.java:529)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.resolve.OverrideResolver.checkOverridesInAClass(OverrideResolver.java:269)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.resolve.OverrideResolver.checkOverrides(OverrideResolver.java:260)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.resolve.OverrideResolver.check(OverrideResolver.java:67)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.resolve.LazyTopDownAnalyzer.analyzeDeclarations(LazyTopDownAnalyzer.java:299)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.resolve.LazyTopDownAnalyzerForTopLevel.analyzeDeclarations(LazyTopDownAnalyzerForTopLevel.java:77)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.resolve.LazyTopDownAnalyzerForTopLevel.analyzeFiles(LazyTopDownAnalyzerForTopLevel.java:69)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.resolve.jvm.TopDownAnalyzerFacadeForJVM.analyzeFilesWithJavaIntegration(TopDownAnalyzerFacadeForJVM.java:147)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.resolve.jvm.TopDownAnalyzerFacadeForJVM.analyzeFilesWithJavaIntegrationWithCustomContext(TopDownAnalyzerFacadeForJVM.java:100)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler$2.invoke(KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.java:307)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler$2.invoke(KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.java:300)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.common.messages.AnalyzerWithCompilerReport.analyzeAndReport(AnalyzerWithCompilerReport.java:232)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.analyze(KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.java:299)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.analyzeAndGenerate(KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.java:282)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.compileBunchOfSources(KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.java:208)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.K2JVMCompiler.doExecute(K2JVMCompiler.java:189)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.K2JVMCompiler.doExecute(K2JVMCompiler.java:49)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.common.CLICompiler.exec(CLICompiler.java:148)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.tasks.AbstractKotlinCompile.callCompiler(Tasks.kt:86)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.tasks.AbstractKotlinCompile.compile(Tasks.kt:62)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at org.gradle.internal.reflect.JavaMethod.invoke(JavaMethod.java:63)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory$StandardTaskAction.doExecute(AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory.java:218)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory$StandardTaskAction.execute(AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory.java:211)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory$StandardTaskAction.execute(AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory.java:200)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractTask$TaskActionWrapper.execute(AbstractTask.java:579)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractTask$TaskActionWrapper.execute(AbstractTask.java:562)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeAction(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:80)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:61)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:46)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.PostExecutionAnalysisTaskExecuter.execute(PostExecutionAnalysisTaskExecuter.java:35)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.execute(SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.java:64)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ValidatingTaskExecuter.execute(ValidatingTaskExecuter.java:58)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.execute(SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.java:42)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:52)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:53)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.java:43)
```

I'm aware that the trait can be implemented "manually" inside of the class body but this will break the data class as *equals*, *hashCode* and *copy* will ignore added properties.

Comment: Please report the issue to [the tracker](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/newIssue?project=KT)

Comment: You can fix your code by using the same property kind(`val`/`var`) in both side(trait and data class).

Comment: What's the purpose of making one _offset_ mutable (var) and the other immutable (val)?  That's not a minor difference.

Comment: @bashor You are right. It was my mistake of using "var" what was causing the problem. Thank you! If you submit it as an answer I will accept it.

Comment: @atok done. Related issue: [KT-6759](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-6759)

Comment: The issue mentioned above KT-6759 has been marked dupe of another issue which was marked as fixed.  So the compiler crash shouldn't happen in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can fix your code by using the same property kind(`val`/`var`) in both side(`trait` and `data class`).

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for achieving multiple inheritence in Kotlin, came across trait. But later found that traits do not exist anymore and their semantics have changed significantly once renamed to interfaces to match Java 8 semantics.

The keyword trait was a keyword in Kotlin but now it's removed. It was deprecated on the Kotlin M12 release.

You can find more [here](https://blog.jetbrains.com/kotlin/2015/04/upcoming-changes-and-more/).